# Ignore minimum size when resizing QWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qwidget

Is there a way to make a QWidget (and any subclass of it) completely ignore its minimum size? What I want is for a QPushButton to cut off when it is sized too small, rather than prevent the window from resizing (the default behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.Ignored)
```

but you'll have to set the initial size yourself.
Or you can just set the minimum size to a small non-zero value:

```
button.setMinimumSize(1,1)
```

To apply that to all buttons within a widget, you could try to use a style sheet, but the borders don't disappear when the button is at its minimum content size (at least with `QGtkStyle` on Linux):

```
dialog.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { min-height: 0px; min-width: 0px }");
```

Comment: Is there a way to get this to apply to the child widgets as well?

Comment: And is there a way to control which widgets will clip first?

Comment: Apparently, if you set stretch values for the widgets when you insert them into the layout, the ones with the lowest value are clipped first.

Comment: Qt seems to always clip the smallest widgets first, regardless of the stretch values. Any other ideas?

Comment: @DK Then you should probably write you own layout class (like [FlowLayout example](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/master/examples/layouts/flowlayout.py)).

Comment: Now there is only one more problem: setting the minimum size for a `QLabel` (and a `QLabel` only, it seems), doesn't effect the minimum size of the `QLabel`. What do I have to do for this? I have already tried word wrapping, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Never mind. I just reimplemented `minimumSizeHint` (although I don't know why I needed to).