# PyQt5 - let QSpinBox shrink, so QSlider can expand, in a QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I've used the code posted below, which has a QHBoxLayout, with a QSlider and QSpinBox inside. Unfortunately, what I get is this:

[image: pyqt5-tester.png]

... that is, the QSpinBox takes up most of the width/horizontal space, while the QSlider is shrunk/compressed to the point of being unusable. I otherwise expected that these two elements would be of equal width when the program starts, and they would stretch as I stretch the window (they indeed do stretch, however, up to a certain point: QSpinBox keeps its width, and only QSlider stretches).

So, how can I have these two elements behave, such that at startup, each of them takes up 50%, that is, half of the width - and they keep that ratio as the window is scaled?

Code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):

    self.slider_hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    self.tslider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
    self.tslider.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.tslider.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBothSides)
    self.tslider.setTickInterval(10)
    self.tslider.setSingleStep(1)

    self.tslider.setMinimum(10)
    self.tslider.setMaximum(100)
    self.tslider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_tslider_change)

    self.tspinbox = QSpinBox()

    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.tslider, 1)
    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.tspinbox, 1)

    self.setLayout(self.slider_hbox)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 220, 170)
    self.setWindowTitle('Tester')
    self.show()

  @pyqtSlot()
  def on_tslider_change(self):
    print("on_tslider_change {}".format(self.tslider.value()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I think I found the solution, thanks to [Ignore minimum size when resizing QWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534644/ignore-minimum-size-when-resizing-qwidget) ; all one needs is to add the line: `self.tspinbox.setMinimumSize(1,1)`, for instance here:

```
...
    self.tslider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_tslider_change)

    self.tspinbox = QSpinBox()
    self.tspinbox.setMinimumSize(1,1)

    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.tslider, 1)
...
```

Comment: Or `app.setStyle("fusion")` Or `self.tslider.setSizePolicy(self.tspinbox.sizePolicy())`